# mysql finding all the descendants for the manager

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT  @id :=   
    (     
     SELECT  id_person    
     FROM    table1    
    WHERE   id_manager = @id and org_enrollment = 'org1'   
    ) as person    
 FROM    (     
        SELECT  @id := 'L003'    
        ) vars     
 STRAIGHT_JOIN      
        table2      
 WHERE   @id IS NOT NULL;
```

The above query works fine if the manager has one reportee(successfully returns all the employee hierarchical) , if he has more than one reportee its throwing the error : subquery returns more than one row. could any one help me get proper result

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: trying to get all the descendants for the manager

Comment: You can't select a multitude of values into a scalar variable. Couldn't you just do `SELECT  id_person FROM table1 WHERE id_manager = @id and org_enrollment = 'org1'`?